# Returning into with WHERE NOT EXISTS

Tags: oracle, plsql

What I am trying to achieve here is, in **single statement** how to get return values using **returning into**.

I am using the following code but getting syntax error.

```
set serveroutput on;
DECLARE
  D_ID NUMBER DEFAULT 0;
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO admin_depts
                (name,
                 description,
                 created_by,
                 status)
    SELECT 'SMS',
           'SMS Team',
           'admin',
           'PEN'
      FROM dual 
     WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                         FROM admin_depts
                        WHERE name = 'SMS') RETURNinG ID INTO D_ID;

   dbms_output.put_line(D_ID);
END;
```

Comment: You get a syntax error since its not a valid syntax! Simple! Returning can hold a single value but the select you have could return multiple rows.

Comment: @Annjawn, SELECT 'SMS', 'SMS Team', 'admin', 'PEN' FROM dual will return only one row

Comment: Yes in your case it "may" but oracle was not designed keeping just your query in mind. A select query returns multiple rows most of the time, but it could also return one or no rows, how would RETURNING know about that?

Answer (score 2):

Insert...select...returning is [not supported](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=413).

There are some suggested workarounds in the referenced article.